# Manual perspective division

Tags: glsl, perspective, vertex-shader, vulkan

I needed to do a manual perspective division on something other than *gl_Position*, when I noticed my results were off, so I did some experiments.

I've noticed that if I let it use the default transformation, the resulting depth value (*gl_Position.z*) is correct:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP *vertexPosition;
}
```

However, when trying to do the perspective division manually, the depth value is **not** the same, even though it should be equivalent(?):

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP *vertexPosition;
    gl_Position.xyz /= gl_Position.w;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

So, does the perspective division work differently in Vulkan? If so, how?

The depth range for the viewport is set to [0,1], in case that has any effect on this.

Comment: sounds a bit like the difference between perspective correct interpolation and screenspace interpolation. That would be the same in opengl

Comment: Define "is not the same". Are you trying to do a floating-point comparison between the two cases?

Answer (score -1):

Vulkan has a number of invariance rules, specified in Appendix D. *None of these rules* state that the fixed-function vertex post-processing steps outlined in Chapter 23 will be invariant with the *vertex shader* attempting to do the same thing. As such, you cannot expect these two operations to yield invariant results.